# Angular Pass String to Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-forms

This seems like it should be easy to do, but I am not sure why this isn't working.  All I want to do is pass this string to the function.

I've tried this.

```
<form ng-submit="edit(type)" ng-init="type='debt'">
```

I've tried this as well.

```
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl">      

  <form ng-submit="edit('debt')">
        <input type="submit" value="ADD">
  </form>

</div>
```

and on the js side.

```
app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $cookies, $http){

    $scope.edit = function(typ){
    alert(typ);
    }

});
```

All I want to do is alert out that word 'debt'.  All I get is undefined.

Comment: could you show us some more code which you have used..by above code it should obviously going to work,,

Comment: I added the controller that I am using.

Comment: Still don't understand how you are firing that `ng-submit` event?

Comment: My fault there it is.

Comment: It seems working here..don;t understand the problem..could you reproduce it here http://plnkr.co/edit/OhzkCiN7HKYQi7FvwaN0?p=preview  Any console errors?

Comment: Here it is http://plnkr.co/edit/6FUFyRza90wYYPHDQHAl?p=preview if you  can figure that out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of you code is working fine, as you included `$cookies` dependency without having `angular-cookies.js` included in your app (module name `ngCookies`), it was breaking your page. Eiether you want `$cookies` there then add the respective reference. Or remove that `$cookies` reference.

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dwM39AKlxdW960GFMgIb?p=preview)